# Calculating expectations values from density matrix in position basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator

given I know the density matrix elements in position basis as a function of time.

$ \langle x | \rho(t) |x' \rangle$

How do I calculate the expection values like $\langle x^2(t)  \rangle $ or $ \langle p^2(t) \rangle$ from this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expectation values are calculate with this formula

$$
\langle \hat A \rangle = Tr(\hat A \rho) = Tr(\rho \hat A).
$$

Since the trace is basis-independent you can evaluate the trace in an arbitrary basis $\{ |n\rangle \}$

$$
Tr(\hat A \rho) = \sum_n \langle n | \hat A \rho | n \rangle =  \sum_n \langle n | \hat A \sum_m | m \rangle  \langle m |\rho | n \rangle = \sum_{n,m} \langle n | \hat A | m \rangle \langle m | \rho | n \rangle,  
$$

where we have used a completeness relation $\sum_m |m \rangle \langle m|$. Now you can simply use the position basis instead of the arbitrary basis $\{ |n\rangle \}$.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it myself:

$\rho = \int dx dx' \langle x |\rho| x' \rangle |x \rangle \langle x' |$

Then it follows:

$\langle x^2 \rangle = \int dx \langle x |\rho| x \rangle x^2$,

right?

Comment: Yes, looks good!